# Problemas con php al re instalar apache

Tags: ubuntu, php7, apache2

recibi un servidor en ubuntu 14.04, apache 2.4.7 y con php7.0.3 funcionando, era mas que necesaria una actualizacion ya que el problema fue por un ramsonware, por lo que actualice a ubuntu 18.04, apache 2.4.29 y php 7.2.15,
la aplicacion fue realizada en php, al ingresar a la ip ya no aparecia la página pero aparecia en consola el codigo, por lo que modifique el apache2/php.ini asignando el valor On a short_open_tag, ya ingresa a la página de inicio pero al ingresar nombre de usuario y contraseña redirige a una página pero no muestra nada, es más... solo haciendo click en acceder sin digitar usuario ni contraseña envia a la misma página en blanco, estas son las lineas de error.log

```
    [Sun Mar 10 13:13:28.156257 2019] [php7:notice] [pid 10656] [client 192.168.10.254:5147] PHP Notice:  Undefined index: msg in /var/www/html/swdoc/co/$
[Sun Mar 10 13:13:42.563605 2019] [php7:notice] [pid 10573] [client 192.168.10.254:47015] PHP Notice:  Undefined index: msg in /var/www/html/swdoc/co$
[Sun Mar 10 13:38:25.404979 2019] [php7:notice] [pid 10575] [client 192.168.10.254:39264] PHP Notice:  Undefined index: msg in /var/www/html/swdoc/co$
[Sun Mar 10 13:45:37.915613 2019] [php7:notice] [pid 10575] [client 192.168.10.254:39472] PHP Notice:  Undefined index: msg in /var/www/html/swdoc/co$
[Sun Mar 10 14:20:41.013432 2019] [php7:notice] [pid 10579] [client 192.168.10.254:40220] PHP Notice:  Undefined index: msg in /var/www/html/swdoc/co$
[Sun Mar 10 14:54:06.366880 2019] [php7:notice] [pid 10578] [client 192.168.10.254:40550] PHP Notice:  Undefined index: msg in /var/www/html/swdoc/co$
```

Cualquier sugerencia será muy bien recibida. muchas gracias.

Answer (score 0):

Esto se da principalmente por un mal código.
El progamador no valida que un índice en un array exista e intenta leerlo igual. Esto produce un error de tipo **Notice**.

Desde el lado de un sysadmin, lo que puedes hacer es modificar la configuración de php. Para ello editas el archivo php.ini y modificas la variable error_reporting.
Para la misma hay diferentes flags que puedes utilizar, sumar o quitar.

Para este caso, lo más básico sería:

```
error_reporting = E_ALL & ~E_NOTICE
```

Esto signifoca "mostrar todos los errores quitando los de tipo Notice".

Obviamente que esto no está del todo bien, ya que el sistema dejará de mostrar dichos errores. Pero sin tocar el código no tienes otra opción.
Por otro lado el programador, puede y debe capturar estos errores y trabajarlos responsablemente.

También ten en cuenta que desde el código se puede modificar esta configuración.

Esta es la documentación al respecto por si quieres ver más información:
https://secure.php.net/manual/en/configuration.file.php

Y aquí una guía clara al respecto:
https://www.hostingadvice.com/how-to/php-show-errors/